# Get instance variable from previous request in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an instance controller containing data which i need to filter in a separate function within the same controller. From what I've read this seems to be impossible, since the lifespan of an instance variable is only in the request. So in what way can i get a hold of the data in the instance controller which was served in the previous request? I know that you can use hidden fields and store it in session but there has to be a better way?

Comment: Yes, store it somewhere (query string, session, database, etc.). It's the only option for multiple requests. Or find a way to do the job in a single request.

Comment: Without a cookie/session, you have no way to confirm that it is the same user in the next request. Use the session, that's what it's there for. What do you mean, "has to be a better way"? What makes you think so? It's like, "how to eat soup? You can drink it, or you can use a spoon, but there has to be a better way?" :) That's it, man. Just use the spoon :p

Comment: I guess you're right. To start with I thought I needed to pass the actual instance variable in session, which would've required parsing etc. But I realized I only need to pass some params to achieve what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flash?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

```
flash[:my_object] = json_object
```

I don't think it is good for complete objects but maybe store the entire object in your DB and falsh the id. Or just flash some key parameters.

Comment: This is great, i only need some parameters in order to achieve what i want :) Thanks!